# Inconsistent Solution Paths in Repeated Runs Using APPSI Interface Solvers in Pyomo

Tags: pyomo, gurobi, highs

I am currently working with the [PREP-SHOT](https://github.com/PREP-NexT/PREP-SHOT/tree/main) energy expansion model, which is based on Python/Pyomo. For solving the model, I have configured the solver as follows:

```py
solver = SolverFactory("appsi_highs")
```

However, upon multiple executions of the model, I observe varying solution paths. This results in different sets of decision variables, even though the objective function values remain constant. To explore this issue further, I switched to the Gurobi solver with the following configuration:

```py
solver = SolverFactory("appsi_gurobi")
```

Again, I encountered varied solution paths across different runs, as indicated by changing [model fingerprints](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360036959831-What-is-the-model-fingerprint-). Interestingly, when I set the solver to:

```py
solver = SolverFactory("gurobi", solver_io="python")
```

I achieve consistent solution paths.

To rule out model configuration as a source of uncertainty, I exported the model as an LP file before each solving and after creating model. The exported LP files were identical for all solvings.

I am seeking insights into why the solution paths differ when using the APPSI interface solvers, as opposed to the direct use of the Gurobi solver via gurobipy.

For replication of this issue, I have uploaded the necessary scripts and data files [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1an6VxusrO7Ylgm1BcklAhqOSQZXcc_fm/view?usp=sharing). They are available for download, unzipping, and execution in the PREP-SHOT folder using the following commands:

```bash
cd PREP-SHOT
conda env create -f prep-shot.yml
conda activate prep-shot-dev
python run.py
```

Please note, running `python run.py` multiple times will demonstrate the differing solution paths.

Comment: I am thinking that what you are describing is expected, normal behavior.  The APPSI solver is carrying its "state" forward to subsequent solves and is therefore not starting the solve process at the same state for each solve.  If you start the solver "from cold iron" for each solve, I would certainly expect a deterministic path on a deterministically defined model.  But this seems totally OK as long as the objective value is the same, it is just traversing a different path to get to the (or one of multiple) optimal solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
1. Coule you please to explain more about why APPSI solver is not starting the solve process at the same state? 
2. I repeatedly run the solving and I suppose I was starting the solver "from cold iron" for each solve. 
3. In most of cases in real-world, we usually focus on decision variable values rather than only objective function value. So, I hope i can get a deterministic solution path for exactly same model.

Comment: I'm not real experienced using the APPSI interfaces, but the first "P" in APPSI stands for Persistent.  Meaning, the solver is maintaining state between solves

Comment: Correct but i am confusion that why i did not get consistent solution.